# pyglet ManagedSoundPlayer on_eos event not working?

Tags: python, audio-streaming, pyglet

I am trying to listen to the on_eos event of the pyglet.media.ManagedSoundPlayer following the examples in the [pyglet documentation](http://pyglet.org/doc-current/programming_guide/events.html) and end up with code like this:

```
from pyglet.media import load, ManagedSoundPlayer

def on_eos():
    print "EOS"

def play(source):
    player = source.play()
    player.on_eos = on_eos

src = load("beep.mp3")
play(src)
```

As expected, I do hear a "beep" - but to my surprise and frustration, "EOS" is *not* printed.

Did I miss something in the docs? Am I doing something wrong? What should I do to make this work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accordingly to [this old link to pyglet Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyglet-users/Y2_2xi3urPM) you need some tricks to reuse on_eos. It is still not implemented. Take a look on the sample from documentation how to implement `on_eos` event: http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/media_player.py

Comment: Thank you. It seems pyglet is not really suitable for my simple needs.